# Why can't I declare a handler outside of a function?

Tags: ios, swift, block, handler

I can declare a handler like this inside a function :

```
    @IBAction func handleActionSheetPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        let dismisHandler:(UIAlertAction)->Void = {(action:UIAlertAction) in
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true , completion: nil)
    }
```

But when I declared this handler outside of a function ,I got a error:

> "Value of type 'NSObject -> () -> ViewController' has no member
>   'dismissViewControllerAnimated'  ".

Can anyone tell me how to declare this handler outside of a function?

Comment: in which class `handleActionSheetPressed` is defined? please show us your code thoroughly.

Comment: a subclass of  UIViewControlller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the `self` instance in the closure declaration in class property, because this variable can be use on another class.
So, you must put an extra argument for the view controller that you want to call dismiss.

```
var dismisHandler:(UIAlertAction, UIViewController)->Void = {(action:UIAlertAction, vc) in

        vc.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```